# In R Studio in a df with 558 rows and 4 columns how to count frequency of non-numeric value in a column

Tags: r, count, rstudio, frequency

New to RStudio. I have a df with 558 rows and 4 columns. The states and cities keep on repeating in the df.

I'd like to know how to count to know how many breweries are present in each state. The columns are:

```
Brew_ID  Name               City         State  
1        NorthGate Brewing  Minneapolis  MN
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no duplicate rows - you can check this with :

```
  any(duplicated(df))
```

if this returns `FALSE` then you can use `table(df$State)`

For example:

```
  Brew_ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
  Name <- c("NorthGate Bewing", "BrewDog", "BigBrew", "Hop Head", "Yadda",    "Blah Brew", "LaLa brew", "Smith's", "Harold's", "Wendy's")
  City <- c("Minneapolis", "New York", "Phoenix", "Sacremento", "Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Portland", "Houston", "Dallas", "Austin")
  State <- c ("MN", "NY", "AZ","CA", "CA", "CA", "OR", "TX", "TX", "TX")

  df <- data.frame (Brew_ID, Name, City, State)

  table(df$State)
```

Returns:

`AZ CA MN NY OR TX 
 1  3  1  1  1  3`

Comment: In case if you want State vs Brew count table: `table(df$State, df$Name)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the table() function.

```
table(df$city)
```

gives you a frequency count of each city. Assuming each row represents one brewery (and you don't have city names repeated in states) that should give you the number of breweries per city.